# In/under this situation

Tags: grammar

Which is correct? *in* or *under*?

> 1. I'm sorry we had to meet **in** this situation.
> 2. I'm sorry we had to meet **under** this situation.

I know that one uses "under" for circumstances, example "I'm sorry we had to meet under these circumstances" but I've seen people use "under these situations" and was wondering if it is grammatically correct?

Comment: Hello, Christie. What does a Google Ngram search for "under these situations" seem to show? And for "under this situation"?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams

Comment: It's just not very idiomatic to use *situation* for your context. Stick with the standard *under these circumstances* if the context is relatively formal, otherwise just ***like this***. Personally, I don't think any native speaker would ever come out with ***under these situations*** in *any* circumstances.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I think they have different meanings. For exmaple Q: "Why did you quit under the situation?" The situation could be "bad economy", "difficulty season for finding a new job" etc. "in the situation" which could be "the individual's bad health condition", "just got devorced" etc.

Comment: @Zhang When you've been using the language daily for almost 70 years, have had a pretty reasonable education, and have spent a lot of time researching the language and reading, you get a feel for what is _idiomatic_. Using "Why did you quit under the situation?" marks someone out as not possessing idiomatic English. _Try googling it._

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, This sentence came cross me, "After two months of hard work, we have a basic understanding of the situations these individuals had awakened under." There is a "situation" and a "under". Is it a variety of "under some situations"?

Comment: We're talking about the idiomaticity of the specific sentence "Why did you quit under the situation?"  Look at "These people were working under terrible conditions" and "Under what condition were these people working?" The second is unacceptable when enquiring about working conditions.  _Acceptable expressions in English are often not what logic might predict._ For instance, "More than one sheep were infected" is ungrammatical, though 'more than one' must mean 2, 3, 4, 5 ... 100 ....

Comment: At least I should say "I came aross" ...

Answer (score 0):

- *In this situation*
- *In these circumstances*
- *Under these circumstances*

All are fine, but not "under this situation".